# My Java web Service returns a JSON String wrapped in html, how can i remove the HTML

Tags: java, android, json, service, gson

I've seen similar questions of this matter but in PHP and C#, my problem is that i'm new to the java web service, and we are using GSON to serialize the results, this results are in ArrayList, my problem is that the response in my android code gets the GSON but wrapped in HTML so the Gson().fromJSon gives an error. I need to remove the HTML

Here is my code, please help.

```
@WebService()
public class Oracle_conexion {

private static final String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.xxxx.XX:1521:XE";
private static final String usuario = "web";
private static final String password = "prueba";
private static String resultado;

@WebMethod(operationName = "getListaClientes")
public static String getListaClientes() throws SQLException {
    List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM xxxx.CLIENTES";

    try {
        conn = conexionbd();
        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        // Recorre el cursor

        while (rs.next()) {

            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.setNombre(rs.getString("NOMBRE"));
            cliente.setCodCliente(rs.getInt("CODIGO"));
            cliente.setCodComp(rs.getString("ORG"));

            listaClientes.add(cliente);
        }// while

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null)
            preparedStatement.close();

        if (conn != null)
            conn.close();
    }
    JsonArray jsonarray = null;
    String json = "";
    try {
        if (listaClientes != null) {
            // json = new Gson().toJson(listaClientes);
            /*
             * Gson g = new Gson(); Type type = new
             * TypeToken<ArrayList<Cliente>>(){}.getType(); json =
             * g.toJson(listaClientes, type);
             */

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(listaClientes,
                    new TypeToken<List<Cliente>>() {
                    }.getType());

            jsonarray = element.getAsJsonArray();

            /*
             * JsonObject jo = new JsonObject(); jo.add("j", new
             * JsonArray());
             */
            // Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            // jsonarray = gson.toJsonTree(listaClientes).getAsJsonArray();
            // json = new Gson().toJson(listaClientes);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    // return listaClientes.toString();
    return jsonarray.toString();
}
```

This is my android Code

```
public class CallSoap {

public String getListaCliente(){     
    //ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://oraclecon.com/getListaClientes";
    String OPERATION_NAME = "getListaClientes";
    String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://oraclecon.com";

    String SOAP_ADDRESS="http://XXX.xxxx.XX:8088/OracleEclipWS/services/Oracle_conexion?wsdl";

    // Modelo el request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);          


    String response=null;
    //Para acceder al WS se crea un objeto de tipo HttpTransportSE , esto es propio de la libreria KSoap        
    try {
        // Modelo el transporte
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        //httpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        httpTransport.debug = true;

        //Llamado al servicio web . Son el nombre del SoapAction, que se encuentra en la documentacion del servicio web y el objeto envelope
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        /*HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
        HttpEntity entity = rp.getEntity();
        response = rp.toString();*/         
        //Respuesta del Servicio web
        response = httpTransport.responseDump;

        /*for (int i=0;i<inpList.size();i++) {
          Cliente x = inpList.get(i);
          //System.out.println(x);
        }*/
         /*Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
         TypeToken<List<Cliente>> token = new TypeToken<List<Cliente>>(){};
         List<Cliente> cli = gson.fromJson(response, token.getType());
         listaClientes = (ArrayList<Cliente>) cli;*/
    }catch (Exception ex){
        response=ex.getMessage();
    }

    return response;        
}
```

And this is my Async code in my test app in the mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public class AsyncCallSoapListaCli extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // private final ProgressDialog dialog = new
    // ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CallSoap CS = new CallSoap();
        String response = CS.getListaCliente();
        return response;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        /*
         * Cliente[] listaCli = gson.fromJson(result, Cliente[].class);
         * List<Cliente> list = Arrays.asList(listaCli); list = new
         * ArrayList(list);
         */
        txtCodigo.setText(result);
        // dialog.dismiss();
        // ArrayList<Cliente> inpList = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        // Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Cliente>>(){}.getType();
        List<Cliente> inpList2 = (List<Cliente>) new Gson().fromJson(
                result, Cliente.class);

        /*
         * Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); Map<String, Cliente>
         * gsonResponse; //TypeToken<List<Cliente>> token = new
         * TypeToken<List<Cliente>>(){}; Type collectionType = new
         * TypeToken<Map<String, Cliente>>(){}.getType(); gsonResponse =
         * gson.fromJson(result, collectionType); List<Cliente> cli =
         * gson.fromJson(result, collectionType); listCli =
         * (ArrayList<Cliente>) cli; textClientes.setText(result);
         */
        textClientes.setText(inpList2.get(0).getNombre());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is just with handling the GSON wrapped in HTML, you can very well handle the response string(removing the HTML tags)before sending to Gson().fromJson(). 
You can make a generic class implementing the **Html.TagHandler ** interface and handle the HTML tags there and later use it as follows

```
txtCodigo.setText(Html.fromHtml(result, null, new MyTagHandler()));// where MyTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler
```

You can refer [This tutorial](http://mohammedlakkadshaw.com/blog/Handling_Custom_Tags_Using_Html.tagHandler().html#.VbgvwPmqqko) for its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, you try to use a SOAP service from a REST client. You have to use same technology both client and server.

With mobile device it's better to use REST service.

**Solution 1**
On server side you are using Oracle, so the following [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r42/RESTful_WS_oll/RESTful_WS_oll.html) maybe usefull for you.

**Solution 2**
You can develop a bridge between SOAP service and REST client. Just to keep it simple, you can write a web application which consume web services from Oracle and produce REST services. For example, you can follow this [tutorial](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/soap-into-rest-apis-with-loopback-node-js/) with Node Js and Loopback.

Comment: It looks great but i have a problem, my boss don't want me to "touch" oracle but as a database, he wants me to use Eclipse Luna to develop the web service and the android app. So i cannot use application express, it's a shame because that tutorial looks good.

Comment: I modify the answer, i hope it helps.

Comment: Ok sounds great, by the way do you know a good and simple tutorial or example and where i can find it?, because i used all the examples that i found on the web to create a service and the code that you see is the only one that worked for me, i tried the server to be glassfish but in the end only apache worked for publishing the service and to return something. As i told before, i'm new in the services matter in java and all this environment. Thanks for your answers, i really thank you.

Comment: Just check again the answer: i update it with an usefull (i hope) link.

Answer (score 0):

jsut add this in your code:

```
response.getWriter().Write(new Gson().toJson(jsonarray));
```